# How to get the AVG of a column

Tags: sql-server

Guys I have this data.

```
  | Server |        Timestamp        | Site | Roundtrip |
      A      2015-12-20 00:02:00.000    MK      234ms
      A      2015-12-20 00:03:00.000    MK      144ms
      A      2015-12-20 00:03:00.000    MK      334ms
      A      2015-12-20 01:23:00.000    MK      434ms
      A      2015-12-20 01:25:00.000    MK      514ms
      A      2015-12-20 01:30:00.000    MK      264ms
      A      2015-12-20 02:20:00.000    MK      134ms
      A      2015-12-20 02:30:00.000    MK      114ms
      A      2015-12-20 02:32:00.000    MK      364ms
      .      .......................    ..      .....
      .      .......................    ..      .....
      A      2015-12-20 23:33:00.000    MK      134ms
      A      2015-12-20 23:35:00.000    MK      414ms
      A      2015-12-20 23:37:00.000    MK      264ms
```

I need to get the Average of the Roundtrip for the particular hour. and combine the Site to Roundtrip and in Timestamp I only need the Hours of that day. Like this

```
| Server |   Timestamp  AM/PM   |  MK - Ave.Roundtrip  |
    A            00:00AM                237.33ms
    A            01:00AM                404.00ms
    A            02:00AM                204.00ms
    .            .......                ........
    A            23:00PM                270.66ms
```

HELP ME Please! I really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datepart` to convert your date to an hour:

```
select server, datepart(hh,timestamp), site, avg(roundtrip)
from yourtable
group by server, datepart(hh,timestamp), site
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92e3c/2)

BTW, I hope you're not storing the the `roundtrip` as a `varchar` with `ms` appending to the duration.  If so, you'll need to tweak the query to convert that value to an `int` before using `avg`.